# Cleanest way to set a default value of a variable

Tags: php, coding-style, code-formatting

I'm working with HTML generation in PHP and I have mainy optional portions of a data display box that depend on what type of data is being displayed in the box. This has lead me to have mainy lines of code that look just like this:

```
if ($sLockIconHTML == "") {

    // Leave a space where the lock icon would have been.
    $sLockIconHTML = "<div class='user-task-box-right-action-icon'></div>";
}
```

What is a clean way to replace the value of the string, but only if the value is an empty string?

Comment: Code length and code readability can have an inverse relationship. That is one line, doesn't mean the code is *cleaner*.

Comment: That sounds like a suspicious design .. ignoring the whole "use a template", there should likely only be "one" output variable (who's name does not depend on the "actual content") for a mutually exclusive display result.

Comment: 1. In each context (i.e. usually inside a function), you should normally know which variables are set and which aren't. 2. The above code will trigger an `E_NOTICE` error if `$sLockIconHTML` is unset (which means: sloppy coding).

Comment: a million up-votes for jason verbose code is much easier to read and debug.

Comment: @lxg this is just a snippet, not the whole code, obviously `$sLockIconHTML` has been defined above, and at some point possibly redefined.

Comment: @TheBat: Yeah, if your PHP code is a huge file, possibly mixed with HTML, and a bowl of `if` and `foreach` spaghetti. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define your variables at the beginning of your script

```
$sLockIconHTML = "<div class='user-task-box-right-action-icon'></div>";
// Later no condition is needed the default is already there. 
// ...and the variable will not be undefined :)
```

Or if your are working inside a function and you want to set a default:

```
function defaultFor(arg, val) {
  return typeof arg !== 'undefined' ? arg : val;
}
function newFunction(variable) {
  var variable = defaultFor(variable, defaultValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There has to be a conditional statement in order to determine if a variable is empty or not, or have a value assigned in your case

```
if ($sLockIconHTML == "") {

    // Leave a space where the lock icon would have been.
    $sLockIconHTML = "<div class='user-task-box-right-action-icon'></div>";
}
```

your code is correct; you can also try

```
if (!isset($sLockIconHTML)) {

    // Leave a space where the lock icon would have been.
    $sLockIconHTML = "<div class='user-task-box-right-action-icon'></div>";
}
```

or

```
if (empty($var)) {
    echo '$var is either 0, empty, or not set at all';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sLockIconHTML = $sLockIconHTML ?: "<div class='user-task-box-right-action-icon'></div>";
```

$sLockIconHTML will be assigned if it has no value.

This feature is available after PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function for this:

```
function default(&$str,$default)
{
  if ($str == '') $str = $default;
}
```

Then each line would be:

```
default($sLockIconHTML,"<div class='user-task-box-right-action-icon'></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

With PHP 5.3 or greater, you can use the ternary operator:

```
                 /* User is not blank,    else:     vvv              */
$sLockIconHTML = ($sLockIconHTML != "" ?: "<div class='user-task-box-right-action-icon'></div>");
```

Its worth noting `$sLockIconHTML` will be equal to `1` afterward if `$sLockIconHTML` is blank.

Answer (score 0):

simpliest way:

```
if ($var === "")
    $var = "data";
```

---

[empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
if (empty($var))
    $var = "data";
```

---

You can't use [isset()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) as some others have suggested since it will return true either case
and false only if your variable doen't exist.

---

a function:

```
function setVar(&$var, $data)
{
    if (empty($var))
        $var = $data;
}
setVar($var, "data");
```

---

[ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) that could be associated to a function:

```
$var = (empty($var)) ? "data" : "";
$var = ($var == "") ? "data" : "";
```

---

this one is a little bit tricky:

```
isset($var) || $var = "data";
```